# Mobile navigation not working from bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css

I am sorry if this is a repeat but I have searched and tried info I have found. Currently when on a mobile, my menu button doesn't drop down or enable me to select any other parts of the menu.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarExample" aria-controls="navbarExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Chunky Geek</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarExample">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="about" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="services" href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="portfolio" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="follow" href="#follow">Follow</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="contact" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please copy the code using the integrated editor; nobody wants to type it …

Comment: sorry, couldn't figure it out at first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so i'll send this as an answer.

Are you sure you have included both the css and js of bootstrap? For example, does this collapsible work?

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes both files have been added as it was a bootstrap theme. I'll go over them again to check for errors

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working for me in [THIS FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jpfg07f2/)

Make sure you are using the proper Bootstrap CDN for both CSS and JS. If they aren't all loaded and linked properly, it will not work. v3.3.7 and v4 are blelow:

[Bootstrap v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)

[Bootstrap v3.3.7](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)